# A tricky integral - $\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^2}-\frac{(n+1)^2t^{2n}}{(1-t^{2n+2})^2}}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$
> \mathbf{\mbox{Evaluate:}}\qquad
> \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(1 - t^{2}\right)^2} -
> \frac{\left(n + 1\right)^{2}\,t^{2n}}{\left(\, 1 - t^{2n+2}\,\,\right)^{2}}}
> \,\,\mathrm{d}t
> $$
>   where $n$ is any positive integer.

**Introduction**: This integral came up while studying the distribution of the roots of random polynomials - and I can't crack it. It seems impervious to methods of integration I know. Neither Mathematica nor Wolfram-Alpha could find a closed form, not only for this general integral, but any special case of $n>1$.

**My attempt:**

> For $n=1$, the integral is pretty trivial to compute - expanding the integrand gives:
>   $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1}{t^4-2 t^2+1}-\frac{4 t^2}{t^8-2 t^4+1}}$$
>   Which simplifies quite easily to:
>   $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^2+1}$$
>   The antiderivative of the integrand is $\tan^{-1}{t}$. Evaluating at the limits gives:
>   $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1}{t^4-2 t^2+1}-\frac{4 t^2}{t^8-2 t^4+1}}=\frac{\pi}{4}-0=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
>   However, this method does not work for $n>1$, and niether does any method I know of.

**Numerical values:**
Listed below are the approximate numerical values for this integral. Neither Wolfram Alpha nor the Inverse Symbolic calculator were able to find closed forms for these numbers.

> $$n=2 \qquad 1.01868$$
>   $$n=3 \qquad 1.17241$$
>   $$n=4 \qquad 1.28844$$
>   $$n=5 \qquad 1.38198$$
>   $$n=6 \qquad 1.46049$$

Any help on this integral would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @Qwerty Are you sure you typed it in right? I've tried it multiple times and it simply spits the integral back at me. Could you link to your input?

Comment: One thing which might be useful: $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1 - t^2)^2} -
\frac{(n + 1)^2 t^{2n}}{( 1 - t^{2n+2} )^2}}dt=\int_1^\infty \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1 - t^2)^2} -
\frac{(n + 1)^2 t^{2n}}{( 1 - t^{2n+2} )^2}}dt$$

Comment: the integrand gets peaked quiet strongly for large $n$, so maybe you should think about kind of an asymptotic expansion!

Comment: Have you considered a Taylor-MacLaurin series term by term integration on the interval [0,1]?

Comment: This is known as [Kac formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KacFormula.html).  There is an asymptotic expression in the link, with the 1st term derived by Kac himself.

Comment: @Wiley Very interesting - this provides plenty of references. Thanks. However, that is merely an approximation - can we find an exact closed form for the integral?

Comment: @TreFox, yeah it's possible.  I merely wanted to provide some background and alternative forms of the integral as stated in the link in case anyone recognizes anything

Comment: @Wiley Awesome, nice find! Before I go searching,  do you know whether someone has cracked this integral before or made significant progress?

Comment: @TreFox, unfortunately no and I personally don't hold out much hope.  However, given the citation numbers of Kac's original paper (also Edelman and Kostlan), you might be able to find something for your need.

Comment: @Wiley I'll look through those papers, thanks! Perhaps, then, this is a quesiton for mathoverflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the integral when $n=2$ can be represented in terms of elliptic integrals:

$$
I(2)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left(\Pi\left(\frac23\mid\frac13\right)-K\left(\frac13\right)\right).
$$

Here the arguments of elliptic functions follow Mathematica conventions: that is,

$$
K(m)=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}}
$$
and 
$$
\Pi(n\mid m)=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{d\theta}{(1-n\sin^2\theta)\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}}.
$$

Comment: Wow, neat! How did you arrive at this answer?

Comment: Well, if $I(2)$ is elliptic, I would't hold much hope for $n>2$

Comment: @TreFox extend the integral to the whole real line, and integrate along a half-circle in the upper half complex plane. The integral boils down to two residues (which gives the $\pi/2$ part) and a integral along a branch cut from $(\sqrt{3}-1)i/\sqrt{2}$ to $(\sqrt{3}+1)i/\sqrt{2}$ (which gives the elliptic part).

Comment: @You'reInMyEye Actually, $I{(3)}$ is surprisingly elliptic, and I strongly suspect $I{(4)}$ will turn out to be elliptic as well using similar techniques as for the $n=3$ case. For the $n>4$ case, however, I have abandoned all hope. :)